# best practice to obtain time zone for iPhone vs iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, timezone, cllocation

I am creating an app that requires the users current time zone. If the device being used is an iPhone and the user has their Time Zone set to automatically change, I think I can be fairly confident that localTimeZone or systemTimezone will give me the correct time zone for the user's location.

If on the other hand the device is an iPod Touch, the time zone returned by localTimeZone and systemTimeZone appears to always be whatever time zone is set in the Date & Time settings, regardless of the user's actual location. I tried using location services but, while the lat/long is being provided properly, the time zone offset in the timesStamp I am getting is always the same as whatever the user has set for their time zone setting.

Any suggestions?

John

Answer (score 5):

you could use `locaTimeZone` method from `NSTimeZone`

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

here is an example from our fav fruit company ->  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PhotoSearch/Listings/DateCell_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003994-DateCell_m-DontLinkElementID_7

Comment: He's specifically looking for a solution outside of [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] because of the restricts he describes in his post.

Comment: thumbs up for "our fav fruit company" !

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you roll your own. Your only real option is to use CoreLocation to figure out where in the world you are, figure out the name of the Time Zone you are in by the name and then lookup the NSTimeZone based on that name.... but I don't even think CoreLocation is available on the iPod Touch (I could be wrong).